# Problema em usar o Jaybird

Tags: java, android, eclipse, firebird

Não estou conseguindo conectar no meu banco usando o jdbc de firebird.
o banco é muito antigo e eu não posso descarta-lo ainda, eu preciso pelo menos baixar a lista de clientes e salvar no sqlite.

o problema acontece bem no inicio, quando uso:

```
Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
```

Como se não conseguisse encontrar o driver. Eu vou no "Build path" e adiciono o arquivo jaybird-full-2.2.10.jar mas nada acontece.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remova o jar do Build path.
2. Crie uma nova pasta no seu projeto chamada "libs"
3. Copie o jaybird-full-2.2.10.jar para dentro da pasta libs

[image: Exemplo]

Comment: Só isso? Obrigado mas agora deu outro erro, nem compila o projeto. [link]http://prntscr.com/bbuq6p

Comment: tente fazer um clean no seu projeto

Comment: Consegui compilar, mas ainda não consigo conectar ao driver. Erro: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver

Comment: estranho, está compilando para qual versão do android?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="21"

Comment: pode passar o conteúdo do arquivo .classpath, .project e project.properties ?

Comment: aqui esta eles: https://mega.co.nz/#!7gplyCSS!dXo-v3riIcd_zvmku0incMrsryc650mDArGKncSncrs

Comment: ta muito estranho, no meu ambiente está funcionando mesmo com o projeto configurado igual. Teria como você me passar o projeto inteiro? pode excluir partes do código fonte que você não queira passar...

Comment: cara, vou tentar em outro pc e ver se é algo que esta configurado errado nesse. Obrigado.